For every real function $f$, is there a real function $g$ above $f$ which is eventually strictly increasing?
This is a natural follow-up to my previous question, here: For every real function $f$, is there a strictly increasing real function $g$ above $f$?. My current question is this. Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a function $g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that $g \geq f$ pointwise, and $g$ is eventually strictly increasing? By eventually strictly increasing, I mean there exists a real number $r$ such that past $r$, the function $g$ is strictly increasing.

Leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because I haven't had time to think about it all, but I suspect the conway base 13 function should be a counterexample.

@dezdichado -- $e^x$ is already increasing, unless I'm misunderstanding what OP wants.

If you consider $f(x) = \tan(x)$ where it's defined and $0$ where it's not defined, you are screwed? You need $f$ to be bounded at some point, however if you can authorize to segment $\mathbb{R}$ in a countable number of intervals and ensure $g$ to be increasing on these, you can manage to prove it exists (or I least I guess)

I'm considering using sets like cantor's set and it gives very bad counterexamples so my previous assumption is not even true. Maybe add some other hypothesis like measurability

Define $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational (so $f$ is Borel measurable) and $f(x)=n$ if $x=m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers and $n\gt0$. Then $f$ is unbounded on every interval.

Yeah good example @bof this problem is cursed!

My first thought was the same as Chris Grossack: the Conway Base $13$ function should be a counter-example. This "wild" function from $R$ to $R$ has the property that in any interval $[a,b],$ $f([a,b])=R.$

I guess I have the "worst" (but maybe not it depends on which problem you want to face) kind of counterexample: Consider $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$h(x) =0$ if $x \notin C$ where $C$ is the cantor set
$h(x) = 0$ if $x= \sum_{k>0} \frac{a_k}{3^k}$ and $a_n$ does not vanish
$h(x) = \max \{k , \, a_k \neq 0\}$ otherwise. (we will call these $x$ small and they form a countable set.

And then define $f(x) =  h(x \mod 1)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now on every point of $\mathbb{Z} + C$ that is not small if you chose a small neighbourhood of any of these points (which are uncountable and in any neighborhood of one of these points you have an uncountable number of these) the supremum on this neighborhood is $\infty$.
This forbids the construction of $g$ strictly increasing on a countable number of intervals which cover $\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly you need some limit/continuity condition for such a statement to hold. Here is a reasonable reformulation of this question along these lines. Let $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $g(x)=\max(f([0,x]))$. Show that $g$ is continuous.
